# Process large file in java

Tags: java, java-stream

How to parse large file like `1.2GB` where total lines in file is `36259190`. How to parse each line to an object and save it in a list.

I get each time an `OutOfMemmoryError`.

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

public void m2() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(DATAFILE))) {
        reader.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
        .skip(0)
        .forEach(p -> points.add(newPoint(p[0], p[1], p[2])));
    }
}


class Point {
    String X;
    String Y;
    String Z;
}
```

Comment: Let java have a larger heap.

Comment: What is the point of `skip(0)`?

Comment: I tried that but still getting the same err . I edit the runtime params to -Xmx2048m   in the control pannel - java-

Comment: skip first line the headers

Comment: My guess is that you will need a heap of 4-6G for this. You need ~100 million String objects, 36 million Point objects, an Object[] sized at 36 million.

Comment: Are the string point values unique? if there is a lot of repetition in point values, you could call `intern()` to have multiple references to the same `String` object, which could significantly reduce memory use.

Comment: How many times do you call your `m2()` method? You have `points` list declared as a class field. So if you call `m2()` several times, your list will store several copies of your file. Does error happens on the first call? BTW, if you need to collect `Stream` items, consider using `Stream.collect(Collector)` method: `List<Point> points = reader.lines().skip(0).map(s -> s.split(",)).map(p -> new Point(p[0], p[1], p[2])).collect(Collectors.toList())`. Then you can assign your class field value: `this.points = points`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer by Shiro is correct, allocate more memory to Java.

## Database

If you cannot afford the memory, then use a database. For example, Postgres or H2.

One of the purposes for a database is to persist data to storage while efficiently handling memory for queries and for loading data as needed.

As you read each line of the data file, store immediately in the database. Later query for needed records. Instantiate objects in memory only for the needed rows from that query’s result set.

Comment: Another more single-processish option would be SQLite.

Comment: SQLite is quite 'lite'. [As its inventor had said](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-05/what-i-learned-about-sqlite-at-a-postgresql-conference), SQLite is meant more as a replacement for storing data in plain text files than as a competitor amongst serious databases. For efficiently handling 32 million rows in limited memory, I would definitely recommend Postgres, and possibly H2, but not SQLite.

Comment: One should not underestimate the power of SQLite. On 4 cores i7 with 8Gb of RAM: 36259190 inserts 5.7 minutes. Indexing by one field (X) 80 seconds. Querying via index - 1 (one) millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

Care for your data types. I’m quite sure that your points do not consist of three text fragments. So define the fields of `Point` according to the actual type, e.g. using `int` or `double`. These primitive data types consume significantly less memory than their `String` representation.

```
class Point {
    double x, y, z;
    Point(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    Point(String x, String y, String z) {
        this.x = Double.parseDouble(x);
        this.y = Double.parseDouble(y);
        this.z = Double.parseDouble(z);
    }
}
```

Then collect your data file as

```
public List<Point> m2() throws IOException {
    try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(DATAFILE))) {
        return reader.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
            .map(a -> new Point(a[0], a[1], a[2]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Then, as noted by others, care for the memory allocated for your JVM. Using the point class above, you can handle 36 Mio instances using a heap of ~1½ GiB without problems…

Answer (score 1):

You need to use command line arguments -Xms (min memory) -Xmx (max memory).

Examples:

```
-Xmx4G (4GB)
-Xmx200M (200MB)
java -jar program.jar -Xmx8G
```

Comment: And it's hard for me to imagine what you're supposed to DO with "36 million objects!"  **:-O**!!  Unless your algorithm is *really* going to do something with every single one of them, every time, I would consider some other strategy which, perhaps, grabs all 36.2 million *text lines* into an array, but creates (and destroys) *objects* on-demand.  Create the object for line# *X* "just in time," then dispose of or reuse the object as soon as possible.  Because of the enormous virtual-memory working set size that the stated approach calls for, it'll run like a dog on most machines, if at all.

Comment: I edited my post so that you can see what I mean. This will give your JVM a maximum amount of 8GB of RAM.